# RestSharp doesn't seem to be serializing/deser my class that has DateTime fields

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have a model that I am using in my web-api layer and with my restsharp based client.

It has datetime fields like:

```
public class User 
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public DateTime Created {get;set;}
   public DateTime Updated {get;set;}

}
```

When I am debugging my code, I can see the following happening:

1. I create and init my class correctly and I can see the DateTime value which VS is showing to be:

   14/08/2014  (day, month and year).
2. When my restsharp client makes a request to my web-api layer I set a break point in my web-api controller and I can see that the datetime fields are all empty.

   01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM
3. My Save operation fails because the datetime values are not in the acceptable range for sql server.

Since DateTime is a built-in type this should work correctly.   What am I doing wrong?

If I reset the datetime fields before saving to `DateTime.Now` it saves correctly.

**Update**

My Restsharp client code has the following method:

```
 public Token SaveUser(User user)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest();

            request.Resource = "Users/SaveUser";
            request.Method = Method.POST;

            request.AddObject(user);

            return Execute<User>(request);
        }
```

When I set a breakpoint in SaveUser, I can see the datetime value is correct.

The breakpoint in my web-api controller shows the user object with empty datetime values.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SaveUser")]
    public SaveUserResponse SaveUser(User user)
    {
    ....
    }
```

**Fiddler**

Using fiddler my request (using AddObject) looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:60525/api/Users/SaveUser HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/104.4.0.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:60528
Content-Length: 292
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

Id=0&Name=abc&Created=15%2F08%2F2014%2011%3A58%3A14%20AM&Updated=15%2F08%2F2014%2011%3A58%3A14%20AM
```

Any reason why the date's are coming back null on the web-api side?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is on the client side?  Try capturing the server output with Fiddler, or calling the API from a browser.  Verify that the data is indeed being sent out of the API.  If it is, then please post more code of how you are calling the api from your client.

Comment: @MattJohnson in the meantime I have posted what my client and web-api code looks like.

Comment: Does it work if you use `AddBody` instead of `AddObject`?

Comment: @MattJohnson When I used AddBody, at the web-api controller level the user object is null.

Comment: See my answer below.  Still, you should check with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to make sure the request is being generated as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `request.AddBody` instead of `request.AddObject`.

- `AddObject` adds each property of the object as separate parameters.  The body is encoded similar to how an HTML `<Form>` submission would work.
- `AddBody` serializes the contents of the object to the body of the request.

You may also want to use `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;` to be explicit about the format to send.

You may also need `[FromBody]` attribute on your WebAPI controller:

```
public SaveUserResponse SaveUser([FromBody] User user)
```

As an aside - it would be more "RESTful" to name your controller route "Users" rather than "SaveUser".  By `POST`ing to the `Users` controller, that should indicate a save.

Comment: I added [FromBody] and the user object is still null.

Comment: Did you verify the request in Fiddler?

Comment: I have to get fiddler still, IT department runs a tight ship and I need approval!

Comment: Strange, when my SaveUser is called (the Execute method) I don't see anything in fiddler showing the request to localhost:60525 (my web-api endpoing) but I do jump to the endpoint in debugger so it is getting called.  Why isn't fiddler picking up the restsharp client call to web-api?

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost

Comment: And with `AddBody`?  Also, consider specifying the request format explicitly. See my edit.

Comment: It works thanks, yes I used AddBody but what made it work was setting the RequestFormat to json.  Thanks for your help!